# Array cannot be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, typeerror

I have written a basic program of calculations. The program runs fine for some input, while gives TypeError for others. I can't figure out the reason behind this unpredictable behavior. Here's my code -

```
class Conversion
I = 1, V = 5, X = 10, L = 50, C = 100, D = 500, M = 1000
result = 0
puts "enter the string"
input = gets.chomp.upcase
temp = input.split(//)
for i in temp do
    case i
        when 'M'
            result = result + M
        when 'D'
            result = result + D
        when 'C'
            result = result + C
        when 'L'
            result = result + L
        when 'X'
            result = result + X
        when 'V'
            result = result + V
        when 'I'
            result = result + I
        end
   end
   puts result
end
```

The error log is as-

> assignment1.rb:22:in `+': Array can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
>       from assignment1.rb:22:in`block in '
>       from assignment1.rb:7:in `each'
>       from assignment1.rb:7:in`'
>       from assignment1.rb:1:in `'

Now, when I supply input like mxcd, dcm, lxv etc it works fine. But for inputs like xvi, ivx, icd it gives TypeError.

Need help with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Sidenote_: you algorithm is btw incorrect. Numerals in preposition to higher numerals are to be subtracted.

Comment: yes I ultimately have to incorporate that in my algorithm, was actually going step by step, have lot many things to implement into this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I = 1, V = 5, X = 10, L = 50, C = 100, D = 500, M = 1000
```

is interpreted as

```
I = ( 1, V = 5, X = 10, L = 50, C = 100, D = 500, M = 1000)
```

resulting in

```
I = [1, V = 5, X = 10, L = 50, C = 100, D = 500, M = 1000]
```

Substitute the comma's for semicolons.

Comment: I would suggest `result += const_get(i)` as well.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.. reduced my code lines :) thanks @mudasobwa

Comment: @Niyanta I would suggest a hash structure and a more rubyesque loop using `inject` or `reduce` rather than `for`. I have reduced your code to 3 lines sans the class definition

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a Hash instead of a bunch of constants like so:

```
class Conversion
  CONVERSIONS ={'I' => 1, 'V' => 5, 'X' => 10, 'L' => 50, 'C' => 100, 'D' => 500, 'M' => 1000}.freeze
  puts "enter the string"
  gets.chomp.upcase.split(//).inject(0) { |sum, i| sum + CONVERSIONS[i].to_i }
end
```

Comment: I am using constants because I have to emphasize them being the CONSTANT values in my program. Your solution would have been perfect otherwise. Thanks :)